# Selectpicker de bootstrap no se despliega

Tags: javascript, bootstrap, select2, jquery-datepicker

Tengo un varios selectpicker y cuando pero al darle click no se despliega, no funciona,tengo que abrir la consola del navegador, no se en que orden deba colocar los archivos javascript, inicializo la funcion pero de todas formas no carga, no funciona correctamente y no se por qué, jquery esta importado en la pagina principal, esta pagina esta cargada a traves de una peticion $.get con ajax.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Este es el codigo:

```
<div class="data-table-area" style>
  <div class="container">
    <form action="pages/gastos-reporte" method="post" target="_blank">
            <div class="datepicker-int mg-t-30" style="margin-bottom:130px !important;">
              <div class="cmp-tb-hd">
                <h2>Reporte detallado de todos tus gastos</h2>
                <p></p>
              </div>
                <div class="row">
                    <div class="col-lg-3 col-md-3 col-sm-3col-xs-12">
                        <div class="form-group nk-datapk-ctm form-elet-mg" data-date-format="mm/dd/yyyy" id="data_2">
                            <label>Desde</label>
                            <div class="input-group date nk-int-st">
                                <span class="input-group-addon"></span>
                                <input type="text" class="form-control" name="desde" value="24/03/2019" autocomplete="off">
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="col-lg-3 col-md-3 col-sm-3col-xs-12">
                        <div class="form-group nk-datapk-ctm form-elet-mg" data-date-format="mm/dd/yyyy" id="data_2">
                            <label>Hasta</label>
                            <div class="input-group date nk-int-st">
                                <span class="input-group-addon"></span>
                                <input type="text" class="form-control" name="hasta" value="24/03/2019" autocomplete="off">
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="col-lg-3 col-md-3 col-sm-3col-xs-12">
                      <div class="form-group">
                        <label title="">Tipo de gasto</label>
                        <div class="bootstrap-select">
                            <select class="selectpicker" name="tipo" id="tipogasto">
                              <option>Todos</option>
                              <option>Compra de mercancia</option>
                              <option>Gastos en el local</option>
                              <option>Gastos administrativos</option>
                            </select>
                        </div>
                      </div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="col-lg-3 col-md-3 col-sm-3col-xs-12">
                        <div class="form-group nk-datapk-ctm form-elet-mg mg-t-30">
                            <button type="submit" class="btn btn-success success-icon-notika waves-effect" id="searchFecha"><i class="notika-icon notika-search"></i> Buscar</button>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                  </div>
              </div>
      </form>
    </div>
</div>
<script src="../assets/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<script src="../assets/js/icheck/icheck.min.js"></script>
<script src="../assets/js/icheck/icheck-active.js"></script>
<script src="../assets/js/bootstrap-select/bootstrap-select.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function() {
   $('#tipogasto').selectpicker();
});
</script>
<script src="../assets/js/datapicker/bootstrap-datepicker.js"></script>
<script src="../assets/js/datapicker/datepicker-active.js"></script>
```

Comment: ¿Estás llamando a `selectpicker()` antes de que los  datos se carguen por ajax?

Comment: Si, con el document.ready supongo